# Is there an onPause for the entire application?

Tags: java, android, timer, lifecycle, onpause

My application is a set of Activities and I have not subclassed Application. There is a static singleton class that runs a recurring timer (java.util.Timer). That timer needs to be paused when the user leaves my application.

If there were only one activity, I could pause and resume the timer onPause() and onResume() of MainActivity. How should I solve this problem in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `onDestroy` and `onCreate` are called appropriately, so I overrode those.

Overriding `onPause` and `onStart` for all activities would be troublesome since the timer would be paused and resumed every time a new activity was launched.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `BaseActivity` and pause and resume the timer in `onPause` and `onResume`. Then derive all other activities from `BaseActivity`.

Comment: If you have one actvity (A1) and start another one A2, then:
A1_pause, A2_create/start/resume, A1_stop. So if you dont want to start/stop timer every time you start new activity, you should add some additional logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this static singelton, you could call through `onPause()` and `onResume()` from every Activity.

Put the calls into a subclass of Activity to reduce code duplication.
Extend this new subclass in all your activities.

Comment: Then I'd have to implement onPause() and onResume() in every Activity, which doesn't feel like a good design.

Comment: You could put it into a subclass and extend each activity from that new subclass.

Answer (score 1):

if all your activitys stay open within the application you can use this, and if the app is closed isFinishing() will be called in your onPause()

```
 @Override 
public void onPause() {        

        if(isFinishing()){
//code to finish() all activitys threads etc.....
}            

    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do multiple things:

1. Just do nothing, when user leaves all activities your app will stop and all of your objects, even static singleton will be released from memory.
2. Track the active activity via this singleton, and when no one is active pause the timer.

Comment: 1. In my test, the timer keeps running. I only start MainActivity and then leave it using the "back" button. I keep seeing the debug messages in LogCat. Killing the app via Settings->Apps stops it.